# ASP.Net ValidationExpression for multiple sizes of digits

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm looking for a `ValidationExpression` to allow entering 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 digits.

I used these Expressions but did not work with me.

```
"\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}|\d{12}"
"\d{9}|d{10}|d{11}|d{12}"
"\d{9}?|d{10}?|d{11}?|d{12}?"
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`^\d{9,12}$`" should work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a regular expression that validates an empty asp.net text box or that has a certain number of numeric digits use the following regex:

```
^\d{16,16}
```

This will ensure the text box is empty or has 16 numeric values.